# Org mode: control whether `M-<RET>` inserts a newline or not for plain lists?

Tags: org-mode

In the following text:

```
foo

- s
  - sdljk
```

with point at the end of the block, pressing `M-<RET>` will alter the buffer to then look like this:

```
foo

- s
  - sdljk

  -
```

Same situation, but with original buffer as

```
foo
- s
  - sdljk
```

`M-<RET>` will alter the buffer to become:

```
foo
- s
  - sdljk
  -
```

I have two questions:

1. What controls this behavior? What determines whether a newline is inserted or not? I cannot find documentation on this (`C-h k M-<RET>`, as well as a basic search of the Org manual yielded nothing).
2. How can I change it so that a newline is *never* inserted?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This behaviour is controlled by the variable `org-blank-before-new-entry`. This variable contains a list of two elements, one for `heading` and one for `plain-list-item`. The default value for each element is `auto`, which means Emacs will try to decide based on context if it should insert a new line when adding a list item or heading. If you set the element values to `nil` instead, new lines will never be inserted:

```lisp
(setq org-blank-before-new-entry (quote ((heading . nil)
                                         (plain-list-item . nil))))
```